# How to interpret MQ5 gas sensor readings?

Tags: arduino, sensors

I am trying to get the dangerous value of LPG leak using MQ5 Gas sensor. But I don't know the value from serial monitor that the analog reads. Is the output of gas sensor in ppm?

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide more information for people to help answer the question. You need to provide a circuit schematic, how you are interfacing it to the microcontroller etc.

However, it is unlikely you are getting a PPM reading from the sensor unless you have calibrated the sensor and developed a function to convert voltage (or resistance) to a gas concentration. First of all, you typically need to calibrate the sensor by exposing it to a known concentration of the analyte (gas) and measuring the voltage / ADC reading.  Second, those types of sensors usually have non-linear response to the gas concentration, therefore developing a calibration function is difficult (and you need to characterize the sensor's response to different levels of gas concentration to develop an algorithm). There are many ways to do this, but that can be an expensive and time consuming process. What compounds the problem is that different sensors typically exhibit different responses to the same gas concentrations between batches or even two sensors from the same batch. The sensors are also sensitive to temperature, relative humidity and other contaminants which can skew the readings. These sensors can be useful for generally detecting the presence of the analyte (gas), but typically aren't very useful or accurate when estimating PPM within a reasonable error margin. There are also many variables to control with that sensor such as the heater voltage, heating pulse duration, load resistance, etc. These sensors have MANY cross sensitivities and responses to other analytes (other than LPG).

If you have implemented the sensor as per the manufacturer's data sheet and have converted the resistance into a usable voltage and are reading the values from an ADC, you *may* be able to interpret the ADC readings as general indication of the presence of the gas (but maybe not.. you could be measuring humidity fluctuations), in any case you would likely need to calibrate the sensor and develop an algorithm to estimate the PPM.

Answer (score 0):

It appears from looking at a couple websites that this sensor returns the value of Rs (sensing resistance).

Looks like you will have to calculate a ratio of Rs/Ro (Ro being the resistance of "clean" air) for which you would derive the ppm from the MQ5 datasheet graph.